# Why does MAMP (mac) with port 80 results in forbidden access while port 8888 works fine?

Tags: php, macos, apache, .htaccess, mamp

I just moved my dev environment from an older machine to a new MAC. I like to use MAMP for my general local environment (simpler projects) but for some reason, the recent version of MAMP wants me to use port 8888 for my localhost.

I changed it back to port 80 which is what I had on MAMP on my old machine, and I have some absolute dev links so I don't want the hassle of putting **localhost:8888** instead of just **localhost** at the beginning of my Uri:s

The result was that no resource could be accessed, everything was **forbidden**. Change the port back to 8888 and it works fine.

Why do I get this behavior?

Someone else seems to have had this same issue a month back ([Can't connect to port 80 in MAMP on MAc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66673958/cant-connect-to-port-80-in-mamp-on-mac)) with no solution.

------------------ update

lsof -I tcp:80

```
COMMAND    PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
    Google     973 mattias   28u  IPv6 0x269b774a91275221      0t0  TCP localhost:54383->localhost:http (CLOSE_WAIT)
    Google     973 mattias   36u  IPv6 0x269b774a91275881      0t0  TCP localhost:54384->localhost:http (CLOSE_WAIT)
    httpd     5444 mattias    4u  IPv6 0x269b774a912738a1      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
    httpd     5445 mattias    4u  IPv6 0x269b774a912738a1      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
    httpd     5446 mattias    4u  IPv6 0x269b774a912738a1      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
    httpd     5447 mattias    4u  IPv6 0x269b774a912738a1      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
    httpd     5448 mattias    4u  IPv6 0x269b774a912738a1      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
    httpd     5449 mattias    4u  IPv6 0x269b774a912738a1      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
    httpd     5461 mattias    4u  IPv6 0x269b774a912738a1      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
    httpd     5468 mattias    4u  IPv6 0x269b774a912738a1      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
    httpd     5476 mattias    4u  IPv6 0x269b774a912738a1      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
    httpd     5477 mattias    4u  IPv6 0x269b774a912738a1      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
    httpd     5478 mattias    4u  IPv6 0x269b774a912738a1      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Also, http://localhost/MAMP/ works fine

When I try to access any of my own folders in the webroot I get forbidden:

If I try a first-level folder (i e http://localhost/myapp/, located in webroot/myapp) I get only

**Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.**

But if I try a subfolder or a PHP file such as http://localhost/myapp/subfolder/
or
http://localhost/myapp/subfolder/index.php

then I instead get

**Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource. Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe**

If I configure MAMP to use a different port it all works fine. But I don't want to have to specify a port in my route in dev env since the app I'm working on has some hard-coded Uri:s.

Also, this is a weird behaviour that annoys me =) My other MAC isn't doing this so I'd like to get to the bottom of it...

------- another update

I have moved my web root (htdocs I believe MAMP called it by default) into my user folder (user/Home/Documents/www) if it is somehow permission related, but I don't understand why it then works fine under port 8888 but not under 80... it's not like Apache gets access to my folder based on what port it's running off of...

------- requested info

I occasionally start a node server just to check a guy's work but not running at the moment. When it's on it runs under port 3000-something.

.htaccess of my web/ folder:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-name.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /folder/$1 [L]

Mac version Big Sur 11.3.1

MAMP version 6.3

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is there any **exact** error message you can share?

Comment: @Matt, I hope my answer below helps you, if so please consider accepting.

In order to assist you further, I wish to ask for further information: 
1.) What is the version of your Mac and MAMP. 
2.) Are their other webservers installed on your machine?
3.) Can you please share the contents of your `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple reasons I can think of. I'd like to also propose a workaround for each.

---

Firstly, Mac (Darwin) is based off of Linux. This means the ports under 1024 range are privileged. Any application running in ring 3 (userland) cannot access the ports.

You need to run the applications with `sudo` privileges. This of-course comes with security risk and  should be done only after due considerations. Usually you should not run Webservers (and dev environments like MAMP) with `sudo`. See my last point for a solution, which is often used as a best practice in many production environments.

---

Secondly, there is a high possibility that you're tryin to run it as root, but still the port isn't accessible. This could be due to the fact that the port is already taken up by another application.

To check this, you can issue `lsof -i tcp:80` which I can see you did anyway. Kill other applications that are blocking this port for you. Sometimes quitting application is not enough, you might have to use `sudo kill -9 pid`. More information is in this [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html).

---

Thirdly, A Mac specific problem could be (which I think is the case with you because you arere seeing different errors when accessing webroot and subfolders)that either the gatekeeper is preventing MAMP from accessing the directories, or the `chmod` permissions aren't proper (*because I see a .htaccess complaint*).

- First check if the Mac Gatekeeper `System Preference -> Pivacy & Security -> General` isn't blocking the application.
- Then check if the directory access is enabled for MAMP from `Full Disk Access` or `Files and Folders` available under `System Preference -> Pivacy & Security -> Privacy`
- Lastly you can recursively set a `chmod` 755 permission on your project directories and 644 on the files. `chmod -R 755 DIRECTORY`. Have a look at this [SupeUser](https://superuser.com/questions/260925/how-can-i-make-chown-work-recursively) post for futher details.

---

And in the last, if nothing else works, you run MAMP on some other port and then redirect all local traffic from port 80 that port using `iptables`. This is mostly how webservers are actually configured in the production environment too, if they are not hidden behind a load-balancer or a reverse-proxy. Please refer this [AskUbunu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444729/redirect-port-80-to-8080-and-make-it-work-on-local-machine) post for the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because there are other apps using port 80. One that comes to mind is skype. you could try lsof -i tcp:80 to see which processes are locking port 80.

Comment: try it with sudo: sudo lsof -i tcp:80         i cant try it on mac since i dont use it but it works on ubuntu and it should be the same.

Comment: added the output to original question. Doesn't tell me much, you? Skype not installed on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

> I have moved my webroot (htdocs I believe MAMP called it by default)
> into my user folder (user/Home/Documents/www) if it is somehow
> permission related, but I don't understand why it then works fine
> under port 8888 but not under 80... itäs not like Apache gets access
> to my folder based on what port it's running off of...

This is the issue. I have no idea why the behavior is different with a different port, but setting the wwwroot to MAMP/htdocs and moving my application there solved the probem.

I won't mark this as THE answer, in case someone can explain why MAMP gets permission to wwwroot when it's in my Home folder as long as it runs on port 8080 or something else, and NO permission while on port 80, that would be the best answer to this question...

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Jorge Aranda Fernandez worked for me when I was trying to get a demo version of MAMP Pro working. I have been running MAMP Free for years on port 8888 so I had been trying to get MAMP Pro to run on port 80 to keep them separate. As a linked image may or may not last these are the full instructions.

NOTE: the original author stated this is a fix for port 8888 (it is). However, the original question was about access to port 80 which this also fixes.

Within MAMP Pro

1. In the top left-hand corner of the main panel select the `Expert View` icon for the view mode.
2. From the left select `Hosts` under `SETTINGS`. Then select `localhost` under `Names`.
3. There are 7 tabs visible. Choose `Apache`.
4. Under `Options for <Directory> directive:` ensure the first box `Indexes` has a tick.
5. At the bottom there are 2 buttons `Revert` and `Save`. Click `Save`. You will then be prompted to restart the server.
6. Test `https://localhost:80` in your browser and it should now connect.

Answer (score -2):

When setting up the Apache tab, check the "Indexes" box:

[image: Apache Indexes must be checked]

That will give you access to your `localhost:8888`.

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer in text form, instead of linking to external images